# How to clear cookies of web browser from a button

Tags: c#, cookies

I created a web browser in C# and use this code to clear cookies.

But I'm getting errors..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
    {
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
    }
}
```

Error

> Error  2   The type or namespace name 'HttpCookie' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    c:\users\supun\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER\FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER\Form1.cs   35  17  FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER
>
> Error  4   The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context   c:\users\supun\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER\FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER\Form1.cs   37  17  FACEBOOK GROUP POSTER

Do you have any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you got a reference to `System.Web` at the top of your code, i.e `using System.Web;`? Not sure about the second one without understanding where this code is placed and whether this is ASP.NET or something else.

Comment: no i didn't use system.web . I want to add these button on c# form app

Comment: Well that's your problem, you can't just take a bunch of web libraries and put them in a form and expect them to magically work...

Answer (score 1):

Deleting cookies is not so straight forward. Have a look at this [post](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.sg/2013/02/c-winforms-webbrowser-clear-all-cookies.html):

You need to import:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool InternetSetOption(int hInternet, int dwOption, IntPtr lpBuffer, int dwBufferLength);
```

Then, call InternetSetOption using:

```
int option = (int)3/* INTERNET_SUPPRESS_COOKIE_PERSIST*/;
int* optionPtr = &option;

bool success = InternetSetOption(0, 81/*INTERNET_OPTION_SUPPRESS_BEHAVIOR*/, new IntPtr(optionPtr), sizeof(int));
if (!success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Encountered an error");
}
```

You may have to mark your assembly unsafe under Properties -> Build Tab.